# Hibernate 4.3.11 Ignoring Cascade FALSE

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

Hibernate: 4.3.11
Spring Boot JPA: 1.3.3
Using JPA Annotations

Hibernate is cascading to a List in one of the objects I am trying to save and trying to remove orphans.  Can anyone shed light on why it would be trying to do this when no cascade is specified on the annotation and the cascade-oprphan is false by default?  I have tried to explicitly set the cascasde-orphan to false with the same result.  Below is the class being saved with the annotations.

EDIT: for additional clarification, the List in the object is empty on the save, but there are child records in the db.   It seems like hibernate is persisting with orphan removal because it is running a SQL delete on the table to remove the child records not contained in the List even though cascade is NOT enabled.

It is the departmentGroupQueueList that hibernate seems to be trying to process for orphan removal.

```
    @Accessors(chain = true) // has to come before @Getter and @Setter
@lombok.Getter
@lombok.Setter
@lombok.EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id", "parentId"})
// @lombok.ToString()
@Entity
@Table(name="department")
public class Department implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    /* From Workflow Database Group, From Document Import Database Group,
     * From Workflow Admin Database Group */

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Department parentId;

    /* From Workflow Admin Database Group */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "doc_storage_location_id", nullable = false)
    private DocStorageLocation docStorageLocation;

    @Column(name = "d_name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "d_active", nullable = false)
    private Boolean active;

    @Column(name = "d_description")
    private String description;

    /* From Document Import Database Group, From Workflow Database Group,
     * From Workflow Admin Database Group */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private List<Doctype> doctypeList = new ArrayList<Doctype>(0);

    /* From User Security Database Group */
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "department_groups", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "department_id", nullable = false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", nullable = false))
    private List<Groups> groups = new ArrayList<Groups>(0);

    /* From Workflow Admin Database Group */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private List<DocIndexSet> docIndexSetList = new ArrayList<DocIndexSet>(0);

    /* From Workflow Admin Database Group */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private List<QueueAllowDepartment> queueAllowDepartmentsList = new ArrayList<QueueAllowDepartment>(0);

    /* From User Security Database Group, From Workflow Database Group,
     * From Document Import Database Group, From Workflow Admin Database Group */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private List<Users> departmentUsersList = new ArrayList<Users>(0);

    /* From Search Database Group */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private List<SaveSearchCriteria> saveSearchCriteriaList = new ArrayList<SaveSearchCriteria>(0);

    /* From Workflow Database Group */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private List<DocAttach> docAttachList = new ArrayList<DocAttach>(0);

    /* From Auditing Database Group */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private List<AuditReason> auditReasonList = new ArrayList<AuditReason>(0);

    /* From User Security Database Group */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private List<UsersDepartment> usersDepartmentList = new ArrayList<UsersDepartment>(0);

    /* From Workflow Database Group, From Document Import Database Group,
     * From Workflow Admin Database Group */
   /* @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private List<Department> subDepartmentList = new ArrayList<Department>(0);*/

    /* From Document Import Database Group */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private List<DocumentImport> documentImportList = new ArrayList<DocumentImport>(0);

    /* From Workflow Admin Database Group */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private List<Tag> departmentTagList = new ArrayList<>(0);

    /* From Department Admin Database Group */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "authorizingDept")
    private List<DepartmentTrust> deptAuthorizing = new ArrayList<>(0);

    /* From Department Admin Database Group */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "authorizedDept")
    private List<DepartmentTrust> deptAuthorized = new ArrayList<>(0);

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private List<DepartmentGroupsDoctype> departmentGroupsDoctypeList = new ArrayList<>(0);

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", orphanRemoval = false)
    private  List<DepartmentGroupsQueue> departmentGroupsQueueList = new ArrayList<>(0);

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id")
    private List<Department> subDepartments = new ArrayList<>(0);
}
```

Here is the code from the DAO that is saving the object

```
   @Override
    public Department update(Department d) {
        getCurrentSession().update(d);
        return d;
    }
```

Edit:
The application is using the Struts2 framework for MVC.  The Department object is being created by Struts on the form submmission.  Below is a snipped from the method that is running on the form save.  The dao object is being injected from Spring

```
public String update() {

    if(getModel().getParentId().getId() == null){
        getModel().setParentId(null);
    }

    setModel(departmentDao.update(getModel()));

    return "editResult";
}
```

Comment: Where is the department passed to update() coming from? How it is populated?

Comment: It is using the Struts2 framework which is populating the department object from the save of the form.  I will paste the code in from the Struts action that is passing the object to the dao.  I am still trying to work through this and think the problem may actually be in my manytomany association.

Comment: You need to be loading and updating an existing persistent instance i.e. bind the incoming data directly to the instance loaded from the database or, copy the values from the populated instance to the persistent instance.